# Unable to connect redis (Memorystore) from app engine flex SSH

Tags: redis, .net-core, app-engine-flexible

I have deployed an application build on .Net Core 2.1 and deployed to GCP. I am using ServiceStack to connect the Memorystore instance. But I am unable to connect the redis instance using redis-cli after opening SSH of my app engine flex service. Could you please help me in this regard?